# kodi on ubuntu 20.04 unable to install

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dependencies, kodi

Having trouble installing Kodi on ubuntu 20.04. I did the following as per official guide

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kodi
```

Getting following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (< 6:19.4+git20220304.1555-e12e66e019-0~focal.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: mesa-utils but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-bluez but it is not installable or
                 python-bluez but it is not installable
        Depends: libbluray2 but it is not installable or
                 libbluray1 but it is not installable
        Depends: libaacs0 but it is not installable
        Recommends: libvdpau1 but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: i965-va-driver but it is not installable
        Recommends: libva2 but it is not installable
        Recommends: mesa-vdpau-drivers but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: kodi-peripheral-joystick but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: kodi-inputstream-adaptive but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: kodi-inputstream-rtmp but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install kodi-bin `sudo apt install kodi-bin`  I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi-bin : Depends: kodi (= 6:19.4+git20220304.1555-e12e66e019-0~focal) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libass9 (>= 1:0.13.6) but it is not installable
            Depends: libbluray2 (>= 1:0.9.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: libcec4 (>= 2.1.4) but it is not installable
            Depends: libcrossguid0 (>= 0.0+git200150803) but it is not installable
            Depends: libfstrcmp0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libmariadb3 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmicrohttpd12 (>= 0.9.50) but it is not installable
            Depends: libtinyxml2.6.2v5 but it is not installable
            Depends: libva-drm2 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libva-wayland2 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libva-x11-2 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: libva2 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwayland-client++0 (>= 0.2.5) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwayland-cursor++0 (>= 0.2.5) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwayland-egl++0 (>= 0.2.5) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install others

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils python3-bluez python-bluez libbluray2 libbluray1 libaacs0
```

I get the following error

```
E: Package 'mesa-utils' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python3-bluez' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-bluez' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libbluray2' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libbluray1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libaacs0' has no installation candidate
```

How to resolve this issue, please help.. please please please

Comment: Why did you add a ppa? `kodi` is already in the official repositories.  All you needed to do was `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install kodi` -- Of course your system should be up-to-date before adding new software. Did you do that? If you had preexisting problems with software, it can compound the problems when you try to add something new.  I suggest that you remove the PPA, then run `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo apt upgrade` before you can finally run `sudo apt install kodi` -- pay attention to confirmation messages and cancel if necessary

Comment: See also: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629) --- PPAs are not a preferred method to install software and can sometimes break your system, especially in cases where they are out of date, obscure, or bring in lots of dependencies (esp. when those dependency versions don't match your release)